# Is possible to recover the SS58 `u16` prefix from bytes `[u8; 2]`?

Tags: ss58

I want to convert the `[u8; 2]` back to `u16`.

I found this isn't simply a `u16::from_be_bytes` or `u16::from_le_bytes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c4d36065764ee23aeb3ccd181c4b6ecea8d2447a/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L315-L336

It's impossible.

The information was lost in this algorithm.